# Memory management of Metal resources

Tags: ios, swift, metal, instruments

There some **MTLTextures** of which histogram is to be calculated, this textures changes at every loop iteration so calculation of histogram is carried out in loop using `MPSImageHistogram`.

There is a single command queue on which **a** **new command buffer is created at every loop iteration** to perform histogram calculation.

Memory footprints (from allocation instrument) keeps on increasing due to new command buffer creation in the loop.

**The question is how to clear the allocated memory of the command buffer once it's executed? Or is there any way for restructuring the calculation scheme?**

**In short, how to deallocate the memory consumed by metal objects like command buffer, compute pipeline, encoders etc.**

Comment: All Metal objects are Objective-C objects. Just make sure they aren't retained anywhere if you aren't using ARC. You don't really need to do anything specific, when API Objective-C objects get deallocated, driver should clean up the memory after it's done using those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at `autoreleasepool`. It is intended to be used for iterations, it frees memory each loop.

Supposing your render function is called `performHistogram` you can do something like this:

```
var myTexture: MTLTexture? = nil

autoreleasepool {
    myTexture = performHistogram()
}

//myTexture has been updated and memory should be freed.
```